# Command to Change GPS from SiRF Binary to NMEA Output

Tags: dell-latitude, gps

I have several laptops with SiRFstarV GPS. At power up the GPS is in SiRF Binary mode. Does anyone know the SiRF command that I can send to change the GPS output to NMEA? (via command line - print "" > COM1)

I'm in no way a programmer and having a hard time understanding the SiRF Binary Protocol documentation on Message ID 129. (https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/GPS/SiRF_Binary_Protocol.pdf)

Changes made in SiRF DEMO don't save after power cycles.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The SiRF Binary Protocol contains characters that both cannot be printed by your console and cannot be generated by your keyboard. I would advise to download some terminal program to send hexadecimal characters to the GPS module. The terminal program used for the following instructions is CoolTerm, and can be found [here](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/terminal-basics/coolterm-windows-mac-linux).

To switch to NMEA protocol:

- Open CoolTerm
- Adjust the COM settings accordingly, and open the port
- Open the "Send String..." window found in the "Connection" menu.
- Select Hex mode
- Paste the hex string found below into the textbox
- Press "Send"
- The "Send String..." window can now be closed. The GPS module should now report messages in the NMEA protocol.

**Message ID 129**

```
A0 A2 00 18 81 02 01 01 00 01 01 01 05 01 01 01 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 12 C0 01 65 B0 B3
```